# How to use the new "Simplified Screenshot Submission Process" in iTunes Connect?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

According to [this article](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=08082016a) you can submit a single screenshot size and have iTunes connect generate screenshots for all other screen sized.

I tried uploading a single set of screenshots under the "Submit for review" screen" but unfortunately I was unable to make it work..

What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Itunesconnect doesn't generate screenshot for other size rather it uses one size screenshot for all iphones and one size for all ipads that "you" upload.

What you need to do is

- Go to itunesconnect and click on "Media Manager" for your app
- Lets say you are making a iphone only app then upload screenshots for size 5.5
- Make sure the check marks next to "4.7", "4.0", "3.5" tabs are checked.
- This means that once your app is approved then on App Store will use your 5.5 screenshots and display them as previews.

Similarly if you are making an iPad app then

- Upload iPad Pro "12.9" display screenshots
- Make sure the box next to iPad "9.7" is checked

That's it you are done!

Answer (score 1):

Well I made Screenshots for 5.5 inch and iPad Pro, and it scales down to the other devices. Instead of you having to make screenshots for 4 different sizes you only need to make 1 for iPhone and 1 for iPad.

Once you upload for the 2 sizes ; You need to go into your "Media Manage" in itunes connect, and tick "Use 5.5inch display" for all the empty screenshot sizes. or you'll get some annoying errors.

It really does make life easier :)

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, but you must provide top resolution Screenshot in order to be able to scale-down.**

So be ready to submit **iPhone 5.5 and iPad Pro 12.9**, then yes, you can use these two for all devices.

Apple information is kind of misleading.